# Is there a way to increase the axes' labels' font size using scatter.smooth in R?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

The question is in the title, but for the classic example:

```
require(graphics)
with(cars, scatter.smooth(speed, dist))
```

Is there a way to have the fonts for the labels `speed` and `dist` to appear bigger?

[image: scatter.smooth example using cars]

Comment: use `cex.lab` argument.  e.g. `with(cars, scatter.smooth(speed, dist, cex.lab=2))`.  see `?par` for more details

Comment: Thanks dww. Is it worth leaving the question for others or should I delete it as proposed by the site?

Comment: Up to you either way.  Sometimes people find the duplicates first, so I don't personally see any harm in leaving the question here.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355459/should-i-delete-duplicate-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate